# should json be in a spesific format to be able to loaded in neo4j?

Tags: json, neo4j

I have a json file like this :

```
[    {
      "companyid":14000019,
      "persons":[
         {
            "nid":"58658734"
         },
         {
            "nid":"70791635"
         },
         {
            "nid":"80739423"
         },
         {
            "nid":"2593745169"
         },
         {
            "nid":"58658734"
         },
         {
            "nid":"70791635"
         },
         {
            "nid":"80739423"
         },
         {
            "nid":"2593745169"
         }
      ]    },    {
      "companyid":14000020,
      "persons":[
         {
            "nid":"310154812"
         },
         {
            "nid":"6369545376"
         },
         {
            "nid":"6369919802"
         },
         {
            "nid":"10482253"
         },
         {
            "nid":"4900004766"
         }
      ]    },    {
      "companyid":14000021,
      "persons":[
         {
            "nid":"12755656"
         },
         {
            "nid":"62979086"
         },
         {
            "nid":"12755656"
         },
         {
            "nid":"62979086"
         }
      ]    },    {
      "companyid":14000042,
      "persons":[
         {
            "nid":"48533122"
         },
         {
            "nid":"68344589"
         },
         {
            "nid":"68344589"
         }
      ]    },

]
```

i need to load [this](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2015/07/23/neo4j-loading-json-documents-with-cypher/) json in neo4j in a way that node labels be 'person' and 'company' .i read this link to know how to load json in ne4j. bu t the question is : is there any other way to load this json with its originally format in neo4j? d i have to change its format to be like 'labels' and 'properties'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load whatever JSON you want really, you don't need to modify it before using it. Use APOC - [it's a two click install into Neo4j Desktop](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/introduction/#installation) and not much more work if you're using Enterprise. Note I also had to add a configuration setting:

```
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
```

Again that's easy enough in Desktop - just head to the Settings tab of a running instance and copy-and-paste.

I saved that blob of JSON into the `import` directory of a Neo4j Desktop instance as 'data.json', and then loaded as follows (this is just an example - you can do what you like):

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///data.json") YIELD value as company
MERGE (c: Company { id: company.companyid })
WITH company, c
UNWIND company.persons as person
MERGE (p: Person { nid: person.nid })
MERGE (p)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(c)
```

[image]

When you use `apoc.load.json`, each property in your input JSON can just be used in your query, and you can navigate the JSON hierarchy by separating property names by dots - see that `UNWIND company.persons` as an example of that.

If you want to experiment, you don't **have** to create nodes to start with - you can just examine the incoming JSON and play around with the navigation. For example:

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///data.json") YIELD value as company
RETURN company.companyid as companyId, size(company.persons) as numberOfPeople
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for reply! it works like a charm for small json file,but for 4mb file its takes 6 hours and the graph creating is not finished yet. is'nt it because of the json format?

Comment: I think it's probably not to do with the JSON, sounds like something else has gone wrong. I'd create a new question I think - does it work with smaller files and get slower the larger the file is? I'd be looking at creating indexes on whatever you're using in your MERGE statements, increasing the heap size in the configuration file and considering using `apoc.periodic.iterate` to split your query up into smaller transactions.

Comment: @ Pablissimo  thanks! it works when i increased heap size:)